# How to select multiple max rows from a table date-wise in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to select rows with `max(batchid)` for each day.

Sample table:

```
Id | BatchId |Date                 |KeyValue
-- | --------|---------------------|-----------
1  | 1       | 2016-12-13 12:30:66 |1234
2  | 1       | 2016-12-13 12:30:66 |5654
3  | 2       | 2016-12-13 08:30:66 |1234
4  | 2       | 2016-12-13 08:30:66 |5654
5  | 1       | 2016-12-12 12:10:45 |1234
6  | 1       | 2016-12-12 12:10:45 |5634
7  | 2       | 2016-12-12 08:10:45 |1234
8  | 2       | 2016-12-12 08:10:45 |5634
9  | 3       | 2016-12-12 04:10:45 |9628
```

Expected output:

```
Id | BatchId |Date                 |KeyValue
-- | --------|---------------------|-----------
3  | 2       | 2016-12-13 08:30:66 |1234
4  | 2       | 2016-12-13 08:30:66 |5654
9  | 3       | 2016-12-12 04:10:45 |9628
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You said for each day and then your output has two 2016-12-13? Also you should show us what you've tried so far...

Comment: @SqlZim Its does... two rows in `2016-12-13` has batchId =2 and only one have the max bacthId = 3 for `2016-12-12`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Check [ask] for tips on asking good questions. In this case as @Anand said, it's better to provide some code that you have tried that does not work as this is a Q&A site, not a code-for-me service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `max() over . . .`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, max(date) over (partition by cast(date as date)) as maxdate
      from sample t
     ) t
where maxdate = date;
```

Or, `rank()`/`dense_rank()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             dense_rank() over (partition by cast(date as date) order by date desc) as seqnum
      from sample t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Sql Server allow  `cast(date as date)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Correction and expansion of Gordon Linoff's:

rextester: http://rextester.com/GECAZ46515

```
create table BatchKeys (Id int,BatchId int,Date datetime,KeyValue int)
insert into BatchKeys (Id,BatchId,Date,KeyValue) values
 (1,1,'2016-12-13T12:30:06',1234)
,(2,1,'2016-12-13T12:30:06',5654)
,(3,2,'2016-12-13T08:30:06',1234)
,(4,2,'2016-12-13T08:30:06',5654)
,(5,1,'2016-12-12T12:10:45',1234)
,(6,1,'2016-12-12T12:10:45',5634)
,(7,2,'2016-12-12T08:10:45',1234)
,(8,2,'2016-12-12T08:10:45',5634)
,(9,3,'2016-12-12T04:10:45',9628)


select t.*
from (select t.*, max(BatchId) over (partition by cast(date as date)) as maxBatchId
      from BatchKeys t
     ) t
where maxBatchId = BatchId;

select t.*
from (select t.*,
             dense_rank() over (partition by cast(date as date) order by BatchId desc) as seqnum
      from BatchKeys t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;

select top 1 with ties t.*
from BatchKeys t
order by dense_rank() over (partition by cast(date as date) order by BatchId desc)
```